# I'm trying to find eigenvalues and vectors of a grayscale image and getting error "Matrix dimensions must agree"

Tags: matlab

The code is giving error "matrix dimension must agree". So what changes should i make?

```
%reading a image
I =imread('C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\New folder\fac.jpg');

m = mean(I,2);

I = double(I)- double(repmat(m,10,1));

%calculating covariance matrix 
c=cov(I);

%calculating eigenvalues and eigenvectors
[eigenvalue,eigenvector]=eig(c);
```

Comment: Seems like the problem is `I` and `repmat(m,10,1)` are of different dimensions. What are the dimensions of your image?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that `I` is a 2D matrix. This is necessary for `cov` to work. Secondly, use `repmat(m,n,p)`, where `n` and `p` are such that `size(repmat(m,n,p))==size(I)`.

**Example**

```
I =imread('myImg.jpg'); % 63x83x3 matrix containing 3D RGB information.
I = rgb2gray(I); % 3D RGB to 2D gray scale. Now I is a 63x83 matrix.
m = mean(I,2);                 
I = double(I)- double(repmat(m,1,83));  
c=cov(I);
[eigenvalue,eigenvector]=eig(c);
```